# dpkg - Configuring systemd results in name regex error

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, systemd, raspbian, dpkg

One day, upon attempting to upgrade the packages on my seldom updated Raspberry Pi Zero W, `systemd` fails to be configured correctly due to what seems to be a bad name to `addgroup`.

```
Setting up systemd (241-7~deb10u3+rpi1) ...
addgroup: Please enter a username matching the regular expression configured
via the NAME_REGEX configuration variable.  Use the `--force-badname'
option to relax this check or reconfigure NAME_REGEX.
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Of course, I try to address what I think is its complaint by temporarily relaxing `NAME_REGEX` in `/etc/adduser.conf`, but even with a temporary, highly relaxed regex of `^.+$`, it still fails. What might be going on here? Would it be a bad idea to inject a `--force-badname` option to the configuration? If not, how? If so, what could be wrong?

Comment: Could you try adding a `set -x` at the 2nd line of /var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.postinst, to find out whether it's complaining about the (normal-looking) addgroup at line ~97 or whether it's something else?

Comment: It seems that it is trying to do a `addgroup --quiet --system systemd-journal` and fails there. Trying to add the group manually using `--force-badname` does not solve the problem, either, because it tries to do it itself anyway. Is there a reason why my temporary `NAME_REGEX` does not work here?

Comment: I just realized that I could just edit the script itself and add a `--force-badname`, but I am not sure why it would otherwise fail without the extra option.